# Excel date calculation within a specific week number

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I need to figure out how to get the dates for both the Tuesday and Thursday in the next week.

I'm currently getting the week number by using: =WEEKNUM(NOW(),)+1
I'm not sure where to go from here, please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following for Tuesday:

```
=NOW()+9-WEEKDAY(NOW(),2)
```

`9` because 1 week is 7 days, then Tuesday is day 2 of the week, so 7+2=9.

For Thursday:

```
=NOW()+11-WEEKDAY(NOW(),2)
```

Same reasoning as above with Thursday being 4, so 7+4=11.

The formula basically takes the current date, adds a week (7) and then adjusts for the weekday considering today's weekday.